# i meet some problem when install tensorflow by conda

Tags: tensorflow, anaconda, conda

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3Lli.png)

i try to install tensorflow 2.1.0.But there is a error like this below:

Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve. Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): failed

CondaError: KeyboardInterrupt

终止批处理操作吗(Y/N)? How should i do to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try to install using Anaconda Navigator:

1. Go to Anaconda Navigator -> Environments -> `Your environment`.
2. Click on the dropdown with `Installed`.
3. Change to `Uninstalled`.
4. Search the package you need.
5. Check the box beside the name of the package and finally click on `Apply`.